# Capistrano deploy with two Git repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, capistrano3

Here's my easy deploy script for my Ruby project.

```
set :application, "data"

set :repo_url, "git@github-data:MyCompany/api_data.git"

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/data'

append :linked_files, "config/secrets.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log"

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine but I need to add an additional repo and have that deploy to a subdirectory of the main project. I've tried a few things so far without success. Thanks for any help

Cap 3.8.2

Comment: Why do you need to split your application into different repositories? Is a private gem an option?

Comment: Is your additional repo an entirely separate application? Why load it to a subdirectory of this application? Both need to be deployed at the same time?

Comment: At the end of the day Capistrano is built on top of Rake, so you can always look at what it's doing internally and make alterations by re-defining particular tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer.

Another option is to deploy the two repositories independently to different folders and use linked_dirs and symlinks to connect the two. I use this method all the time.

Let's say that the release path for your app is `$APP_PATH` and the release path for your secondary repo is `$OTHER_APP_PATH`. Let's also assume for the example, that you need the secondary repo to show up at `lib/myapp` in your app.

I would start by deploying your secondary app to `$OTHER_APP_PATH` on your server.

Then add `append :linked_dirs, 'lib/myapp'` to your app's deploy.rb config. When you deploy, you should have an empty folder at `$APP_PATH/shared/lib/myapp` which is symlinked to from `$APP_PATH/current/lib/myapp`. Delete that folder (`rmdir $APP_PATH/shared/lib/myapp`) and replace it with a symlink to the `current` directory of your secondary app (`ln -s $OTHER_APP_PATH/current $APP_PATH/shared/lib/myapp`).

Now the contents of your secondary app should show up in your primary app's `lib/myapp` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Given it's probably a capistrano limitation I see two possible approaches offhand (there are definatly more)

- Make the sub-project a [gem](http://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/creating_gem.html) and include it that way
- Use something like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) which while python code is more of an iterative scripted deploy tool

Comment: For reasons that are too long to explain, a gem is not an option. A :linked_dirs would do the trick if there was a way I could initiate a git pull on the remote side.
Is there such a task in cap I could run.

Comment: you'll probably have to hand roll it via submodules in a cap task like this, https://gist.github.com/corny/7459729 or maybe via a git hook? Apologies but It's been a long time since I've had to deal with a scripted deploy as everything nowadays (for me) is provisioned.

Comment: Another option is to deploy the two repositories independently to different folders and use linked_dirs and symlinks to connect the two. I use this method all the time.

Comment: @will_in_wi I like this idea. How do I specify a :linked_dirs that lies outside my /var/www/my_app_name/shared directory?